# Pass Parameter with href inside HTML Email c# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to send email using my MVC Javascript application.for now email is sending and my hrefs are clickable and redirect to correct link.but my problem is how can i pass parameters with the href

```
emailBody += @"
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <h3><b>Currently Data;</b></h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr style='color: #ed5565; text-align: center'>
                <th>Completed Date</th>
                <th>Category</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";

            for (int i = 0; i < result3.Count; i++)
            {
                emailBody += @"
            <tr style='text-align: center'>
            <a href='http://myTestLink.com/Forms/Upload/' + result3[i].FormID >
                 <td>" + result3[i].CompletedDate + @"</td>
                <td>" + result3[i].FormCategory + @"</td>

</a>
            </tr>";
            }
```

Comment: Missing quotes on closing of `a` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for href attributes: `"' ...   '"`

```
emailBody += @"
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<h3><b>Currently Data;</b></h3>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style='color: #ed5565; text-align: center'>
            <th>Completed Date</th>
            <th>Category</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";

        for (int i = 0; i < result3.Count; i++)
        {
            emailBody += @"
        <tr style='text-align: center'>
        <a href="'http://myTestLink.com/Forms/Upload/'" + result3[i].FormID + ">
             <td>" + result3[i].CompletedDate + @"</td>
            <td>" + result3[i].FormCategory + @"</td>
```

Comment: inside emailbody. it cannot add "" it gave me an error.

Comment: You also use from ` ` for this string in the razor page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make dynamic code for href for passing parameter.

```
emailBody += @"
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <h3><b>Currently Data;</b></h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr style='color: #ed5565; text-align: center'>
                <th>Completed Date</th>
                <th>Category</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";

            for (int i = 0; i < result3.Count; i++)
            {
                emailBody += @"
            <tr style='text-align: center'>
            <a href='http://myTestLink.com/Forms/Upload/'" + result3[i].FormID + ">" +
                 "<td>" + result3[i].CompletedDate + @"</td>
                <td>" + result3[i].FormCategory + @"</td>

</a>
            </tr>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<a href='@string.Format("http://myTestLink.com/Forms/Upload/' + result3[i].FormID", result3[i].FormID)'>
```

Comment: So, are you going to change it? What you've posted doesn't look like it will work, did you test it?

Comment: Pretty sure you didn't test this, there are syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
 <a href='@string.Format("http://myTestLink.com/Forms/Upload?formId=' + result3[i].FormID", result3[i].FormID)'>
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in this, so I don't think anyone should try this.